# enable docker services in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: docker

I've used `sudo systemctl enable docker.service` but the service won't start.

[image: image attached]

Comment: What happens with `sudo systemctl enable docker` ?

Comment: terminal gives this message "failed to enable unit : unit file/etc/systemd/system/docker.services is masked"

Comment: Masking a service is basically making it unable to start, nor automatically (enabling it) nor manually. You have to unmask it as @lependu suggests.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try this (3 separate commands from the terminal):

```
$ sudo systemctl unmask docker.service
$ sudo systemctl unmask docker.socket
$ sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

Comment: this one did it. Thanks a lot.